# getting rat out of a maze

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, data-structures

A rat is placed in a maze at some unknown position in the maze.

All we can go is in up, down, right or left directions. And we have two methods:

- tryMove(<direction>) which returns false if there is a wall and true if we can move.
- bool hasLadder(): which returns true if there is a ladder  to escape.

We have to write a function explore which returns true if we find the way out or false if there is no way.

This is a simple graph problem and can be solved using bfs or a dfs algorithm if we can find mark these places. If we cannot mark these places we can move in cycles visiting the same places. Can some one help me to get rat out of the maze please if its unmarked? Is it possible?

Comment: `while (true) {tryMove(); hasLadder();}` - Sounds like you have no other options anyway.

Comment: Asking us to do your homework for you?

Comment: Do the old keep your left hand on the wall trick to start out.

Comment: @dcp This is not about BFS or DFS. If I dont remember my previous position how can I solve this problem. BFS or DFS requires you to remember previous position

Comment: @Adam I am a developer. I am not in any school.

Comment: @mousey: is your job to write software to get rats out of mazes? This is such a classic homework problem that I am having a hard time understanding how it isn't homework.

Comment: @Adam I am preparing for Interviews This is asked in a MS interview. I cant prove any more

Comment: @Adam Crossland Sometimes people will take widely used examples and use them themselves to learn the language.  Since you can't DEFINITIVELY know whether or not this is the case, don't assume it's homework.

Comment: @mousey: fair enough. But it *is* sorta homeworky-sounding.

Comment: So, you can't mark a node in the graph as visited.  Can you remember anything?  That is, can you have each node remember how long it took you to get there?

Comment: @Paul Check this http://www.careercup.com/question?id=3483900
This is the exact question I changed it little bit

Comment: @Dean J I posted the link to the exact question asked. I was not asked to do this question.

Comment: @mousey You changed the question into something that has no possible answer.  Now that was silly wasn't it?

Comment: @James I just wanted to know whether its possible. Its better to post and get opinions from people than just making my own assumption

Comment: @mousey; they'd expect you to make an assumption or two, I think.  If the rat has no memory, the solution is to do a random walk of the maze, which is guaranteed to complete... in an infinite amount of time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Both breadth-first and depth first search require memory and a naive algorithm can loop indefinitely. A rat probably only has O(1) memory.

One way to solve it without remembering where you have been is to pick a direction at random. The solve time will be extremely long, but it should eventually reach every reachable square. This is related to the [2D random](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RandomWalk2-Dimensional.html) walk.

> Amazingly, it has been proven that on a two-dimensional lattice, a random walk has unity probability of reaching any point (including the starting point) as the number of steps approaches infinity.

Comment: Unfortunately, the random walk strategy will not allow us to return false if exit is not possible, a part of OP's homework.

Comment: @Adam Crossland 
if(time > infinity) return false;

Comment: That answer will definitely get him a job at Microsoft.

Comment: @Mark Byers, since you have no idea of the size of the maze, you cannot even make an estimation...

Comment: @James: Perhaps my computer is defective, but it can only count up to "infinity - 1".

Comment: @Steven Sudit When was the last time you tried?  Mine's still counting.

Comment: @James: Good point if you don't know the size of the maze... but the OP didn't specify whether or not you know the size of the maze, only that your initial position in the maze is unknown. *If* you know the size of the maze then you can probably make a reasonable estimate.

Comment: @James: Nope, mine stops on "infinity - 1" on the dot, quite consistently. Thanks to quad cores with hyperthreading, it's almost 5x faster at a near-infinite loop than a single-core machine at the same clock speed.

Comment: «A rat probably only has O(1) memory.» Somehow I doubt that.

Comment: @ninjalj: Why do you doubt it? It seems an entirely reasonable assumption to me. The idea that a rat's memory capacity would depend on the size of the maze it is placed in seems very unlikely.

Comment: Of course a hypothetical spherical rat on a vacuum may have O(1) memory, but I seriously doubt a real life rat would use its memory the same way on different mazes.

Comment: I don't know about O(1) memory, but I've seen rats solve probability problems better than a class full of psychology students. (No, seriously)

Comment: @Brian: This says much about psychology students, but little about rats.

Comment: @ninjalj: but its memory capacity is still fixed. It doesn't grow new brain cells depending on the size of the maze.

Comment: The rats memory (as well as being O(1)) probably isn't very big either so any solutions will have to be small to ensure they fit

Answer (score 2):

The algorithm is basically USTCON (undirected st-connectivity): given an undirected graph *G*, determine if there is a path from node *s* (the rat's start position) to node *t* (the exit). This problem is in [complexity class L](http://qwiki.stanford.edu/wiki/Complexity_Zoo:L#l), which means it requires a [logarithmic amount of memory](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1060647). So, unless you have an upper bound on the size of the maze, or are willing to approximate, it is impossible with constant space.

Comment: According to the paper Omer Reingold has an O(log n) algorithm: http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1060647

Answer (score 1):

With no memory the only solution is the random one and it's terrible.  If you know the maze is only singly connected you can use a wall-following approach but that can go into an infinite loop if the maze contains a loop.

Answer (score 0):

You should run BFS algorithms. The only problem I see is how to define graph. It can be defined with [von Neumann neighborhood](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_neighborhood). Node is defined as X,Y pair. Pseudo code should look like:

```
BFS
while (!Q.empty()){
    v = Q.top()
    neighbours = get_adj_list(v)
    foreach (w in neighbours){
        if (isWall(w) || isOutsideMaze(w)) skip
        if (isTerminal(w)) printPathAndExit
        if (dist[v] + 1 < dist[w])
            dist[w] = dist[v] + 1
            Q.push(w)
    }
}

GEN_NEIGHBOURS
dx = {-1,1}
dy = {-1,1}

get_adj_list(v)
    adj_list = []
    for (i in dx)
        for (j in dy)
            adj_list << node(v.x-i,v.y-j)
    return adj_list
```

**EDIT**: now I read the memory limit is O(1). So I guess you should follow old method to always turn to the right and you will eventually get out of the maze or get back to start position.

**EDIT2**: from Corn Maze tips:

> As with any maze, if consistently take either the right or left hand turns, you will eventually find a way out. Running your finger long the wall of the maze without lifting it will keep you on the right track.

Comment: LOL try to make the rat tiered?

Comment: The OP said that you don't have the ability to mark a node as visited, though, which implies you don't have the ability to "remember" the distance to get to a node, either.

Comment: The left-hand-on-wall rule only works for simply connected mazes, which this may not be.  Imagine a maze with walls around the outside, a clear path around a patch of walls, and a ladder in the patch.  A rat in the outer area won't find the ladder with left-paw-on-wall.

Comment: @David Thornley you are right it works only for some specific class of mazes that can be called classsic mazes.

Comment: The "hand on wall" algorithm becomes completely general if you add the rule "switch to the other wall anytime you come back to a place you've been before". Basically, anytime you loop around you've explored all of one side of the path you are on, so now try the other side. Of course, that means either remembering where you've been, or coloring your path.

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic problem often used as a homework assignment.

Try this:

1. Can you tell if you are at the way out *right now*?
2. Once you have that, what do you need to do to find out if you are within one move of the way out?
3. How about if you are within 2 moves of the way out?

...

As [Mark notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3471399/getting-rat-out-of-a-maze/3471434#3471434), the simplest versions of the algorithm I'm trying to lead you to can get locked in a loop. How can you solve this problem?

Comment: This looks an awful lot like Korf's Iterative Deepening search.  BTW, loops themselves will only be inefficient.  Only worry if you're locked into one.

Comment: @David: I hadn't know that this had a name. [Mr. Korf's paper (PDF link)](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.91.288) is very interesting. I particularly like the use of working Rubik's cube solutions on a VAX 11/780 as an example.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, I had a recursion homework assignment like this a long time ago, however it wasn't limited to O(1) memory. We just couldn't build 'maps' of where we've been and had to use recursion... I guess this would use O(n) memory, where n is the shortest distance to the ladder from the start.

```
while( 1 )
    {
    if( search( MOVE_LEFT, i ) ||
        search( MOVE_UP, i ) ||
        search( MOVE_RIGHT, i ) ||
        search( MOVE_DOWN, i ) )
         {
         return TRUE;
         }
    i++;
    }

/* recursive function */
bool search( move_type move, long int length )
{

doMove( move ); /* actually move the rat to requested place */

if( hasLadder() )
    return TRUE;

if( 0 == length )
    return FALSE;

switch( move ) /* check each and return rat to previous place */
    {
    case MOVE_LEFT:  
        if( tryMove( MOVE_LEFT ) && search( MOVE_LEFT, length - 1 ) ) return TRUE;
        if( tryMove( MOVE_UP ) && search( MOVE_UP, length - 1 ) ) return TRUE;
        if( tryMove( MOVE_DOWN ) && search( MOVE_RIGHT, length - 1 ) ) return TRUE;      
        doMove( MOVE_RIGHT ); break;
    case MOVE_UP:
        if( tryMove( MOVE_LEFT ) && search( MOVE_LEFT, length - 1 ) ) return TRUE;
        if( tryMove( MOVE_UP ) && search( MOVE_UP, length - 1 ) ) return TRUE;
        if( tryMove( MOVE_RIGHT ) && search( MOVE_RIGHT, length - 1 ) ) return TRUE; 
        doMove( MOVE_DOWN ); break;
    case MOVE_RIGHT:
        if( tryMove( MOVE_UP ) && search( MOVE_UP, length - 1 ) ) return TRUE;
        if( tryMove( MOVE_RIGHT ) && search( MOVE_RIGHT, length - 1 ) ) return TRUE;
        if( tryMove( MOVE_DOWN ) && search( MOVE_RIGHT, length - 1 ) ) return TRUE;      
        doMove( MOVE_LEFT ); break;
    case MOVE_DOWN:
        if( tryMove( MOVE_LEFT ) && search( MOVE_LEFT, length - 1 ) ) return TRUE;
        if( tryMove( MOVE_RIGHT ) && search( MOVE_RIGHT, length - 1 ) ) return TRUE;
        if( tryMove( MOVE_DOWN ) && search( MOVE_RIGHT, length - 1 ) ) return TRUE;      
        doMove( MOVE_UP ); break;
    }

return FALSE;

}   /* search() */
```

Answer (score 0):

Funny that @mousey would ask about a rat... anwyay.

I have seen this problem creep up a number of times already.

The first (and naive) solution is to follow the left (or right) wall, however it's possible to craft specific mazes where the rat end up running in circles.

In fact, for every deterministic order of moves (like 2L, 1R, 2L, 1R, ...) that I tried (being in high school I had time) we could come up with a maze that would make the rat run in circles. Of course, the more complicated the cycle, the more complicated the maze.

Therefore, if you have O(1) memory, the only solution to get out of the maze seems to be a random walk, as proposed by Mark Byers. Unfortunately you cannot prove it's impossible to get out of the maze with such an algorithm.

On the other hand, if you have O(N) memory, it boils down to creating a map (somehow). The strategy I finally come up with back then was to leave pheromon (incrementing a counter) on each case I passed, and when having a choice in a move, to choose among the least visited cases. However it was always possible to get out so I never had to think about a termination condition in case there is no exit.

You can also use a flood fill algorithm...Of course, it was before I learned about the term BFS. This has the advantage that you do have a termination condition (when there isn't any case left to explore).

Answer (score -1):

Determining whether there is a way out sounds a lot like a halting problem to me. It can be solved for all trivial and many non trivial cases but for lots of maps unless you can mark where you have been you can't prove that the map isn't infinite.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem